# Does a random walk with infinite mean ever converge to anything?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose we have a random walk on the real line whose step sizes have finite variance. We know that, when viewed as a function and suitably rescaled, this random walk will converge to a Brownian motion. This is [Donsker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem).

**Soft question:** what happens when the step sizes have *infinite mean*? Is it also possible to rescale these infinite-mean random walks in a way such that their measure converges to a tight law in an appropriate function space (not necessarily $C[0,1]$)?

A quick Google search got me to [Levy processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process), but I had trouble making the connection with random walks. I could just be thick, though. Can anyone point me to a reference which deals with this type of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the so-called "stable FCLT", stating that such a random walk, appropriately rescaled, converges weakly in Skorohod space to $(\alpha, \beta)$-stable Levy motion.  It looks like this is due to Skorohod and the canonical modern reference is Jacod and Shiryaev.

I can't look up a precise statement at the moment, but hopefully this is a start.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I found a relevant source here (in particular, Theorem 4.5.3): http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/jumps.html

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at Kallenberg's book *Foundations of Modern Probability Theory* (specifically Theorem 16.14 in the second edition). A simple example:  the random walk with step distribution the standard Cauchy distribution, which is symmetric about $0$ but has infinite mean.  This random walk (scaled in space by $1/n$ rather than by $1/\sqrt{n}$) converges  in law (in the space of right-continuous, left-limited paths) to the standard Cauchy process.